# C++ create chain using struct cause circular reference. nextNode refer to the same address and value

Tags: c++

The first call of appendChild work as expected, but then the next point to itself. need an example how to do it.

why LinkNode nextNode; not create a new instance

zsbd
zsbd
zsbd
zsbd
zsbd
zsbd

```cpp
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct LinkNode {
    T data;
    bool hasNext = false;
    LinkNode<T> *next = nullptr;

};

template<typename T>
void appendChild(LinkNode<T> &initNode, T &node) {
    LinkNode<T> *ptr = &initNode;
    while (ptr && ptr->hasNext) {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    // end of the chain
    ptr->data = node;
    ptr->hasNext = true;
    // create new node
    LinkNode<T> nextNode;
    // append to the end
    ptr->next = &nextNode;
    cout << "done" << endl;
};

int main() {
    int a = 123;
    int b = 456;
    int c = 789;
    LinkNode<int> initNode;
    initNode.data = 1;
    appendChild(initNode, a);
    appendChild(initNode, b);
    appendChild(initNode, c);
    cout << "finish" << endl;
}
```

Detail on the pause.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwUbX.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkNode<T> nextNode;` This is a local variable. It is destroyed when it goes out of scope. Thus `ptr->next = &nextNode;` will add the address of a local variable.

Accessing it's address is Undefined Behavior.

edit: a modern solution would be to use `std::unique_ptr` (we don't use `new` anymore). E.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct LinkNode {
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<LinkNode<T>> next;
};

template<typename T>
void appendChild(LinkNode<T> & initNode, T &node) {
    LinkNode<T> *ptr = &initNode;
    while (ptr && ptr->next) {
        ptr = ptr->next.get();
    }
    // end of the chain
    ptr->data = node;
    // create new node
    ptr->next = std::make_unique<LinkNode<T>>();
    std::cout << "done\n";
};

int main() {
    int a = 123;
    int b = 456;
    int c = 789;
    LinkNode<int> initNode;
    initNode.data = 1;
    appendChild(initNode, a);
    appendChild(initNode, b);
    appendChild(initNode, c);
    std::cout << "finish\n";
}
```

Comment: how can i create a node that can still be accessed after the func is finished? thx for reply:)

Comment: @方嘉汇 Use dynamic allocation with `new`.

Comment: @john it works after i change to LinkNode<T> *nextNode = new LinkNode<T>; thx

Comment: @john thanks but no thanks. Please don't instruct beginners to use `new`, because now he/she has a memory leak...